# Linq query not returning values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I currently have 2 dbContexts, I am not sure if this makes a difference.  ApplicationDbContext and CompanyDBContext.  The tables have already been setup within the database and I have added data within the companydetails table.

I probably have a couple problems with my code, I am not sure what I have done within the view regarding the companyID is correct, but mainly my question is I am not sure as to why my linq query does not return any results when I have data in my table.

My CompanyDBContext goes as is

```
public class CompanyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CompanyDetails> companies { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my model

```
public class CompanyDetails
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int? companyID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

I have written a linq query which should have got back the one row I put into the the database.  With this linq query I then construct a list of SelectListItems which I pass to the viewbag, and then I want to be able to have a dropdown box with the company name in, in which the user selects.

```
 public ActionResult Register()
    {
        //var regViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();

        List<SelectListItem> companyList = null;

        using(var companies = new CompanyDBContext())
        {
            var companyNamesQuery = (from comp in companies.companies
                                     select new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Text = comp.CompanyName,
                                         Value = comp.companyID.ToString()
                                     });
            companyList = companyNamesQuery.ToList();

            @ViewBag.companies = companyList;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

and here is the view,

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.userCompanyID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userCompanyID, new SelectList(ViewBag.companies, "companyID", "CompanyName"))
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here are my connection strings

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBTest;User ID=x;Password=Xxxxx1;Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DevConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBTest;User ID=x;Password=Xxxxx1;Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Have you used a debug breakpoint after assigning companyList = companyNamesQuery.ToList() to check if there are any returned values?

Comment: Why in your view do you create a `SelectList`? `ViewBag.companies` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which is what is required for `DropDownListFor()` - its just pointless extra overhead - it should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userCompanyID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.companies)`. In any case, `ViewBag.companies` does not contain properties `companyID` and `CompanyName` - only `Value` and `Text`

Comment: @C Bauer I have, and it is not returning any values

Comment: What's your connectionstring?

Comment: I'll edit my post so it's properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, double check your connection string. Either you're pointing to the wrong server, the wrong database, or the data never made it into the table.

This line:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userCompanyID, new SelectList(ViewBag.companies, "companyID", "CompanyName"))
```

In this line:

```
var companyNamesQuery = (from comp in companies.companies
                                 select new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Text = comp.CompanyName,
                                     Value = comp.companyID.ToString()
                                 });
```

You created a new List of SelectListItem. Only the properties Text and Value are available to you on your view.

This dropdown list should be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userCompanyID, new SelectList(ViewBag.companies, "Value", "Text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because I was not using the right connection string.  When I had created the new connection string which did not have the same name as my dbContext I had not passed the connection string to the base class